# Arduino can't read from serial port

Tags: linux, terminal, arduino, command, output

I have been experimenting with my arduino the last few days. I want to read the data from it. In the arduino IDE it says that its port is `/dev/ttyACM0`. I tried running `tail -f /dev/ttyACM0` but the process just hangs and nothing happens.

If I enable the serial monitor in the arduino IDE and then run the command it says that the port is used so I am sure that this is the correct port. In the serial monitor I can see that arduino outputting strings. Can anyone please help me troubleshoot this issue? I am using linux.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Difference between /dev/ttyACM0 and /dev/ttyS0 (Arduino IDE ports under Linux)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19648/difference-between-dev-ttyacm0-and-dev-ttys0-arduino-ide-ports-under-linux)
 Maybe there is where your problem lies

> If you want to use /dev/ttyS0 (why would you?!) you will require a
>   special cable that converts the RS-232 voltage signals from the 9-pin
>   D connector into the right TTL level signals for the Ardiuno and wire
>   it in to the right pins on the board.

I hope this can help you!